# Does a power amplifier dissipate power in its source impedance?

Tags: impedance-matching

If I have a power amplifier (or other signal generating device) that has a source impedance of 50 Ohms and drives 1W into a 50 Ohm load, does it also dissipate 1W in its source impedance?

My current mental model of the situation is that there will be 1W = I^2 * 50 Ohms => I = sqrt(1W/50Ohms) ~ 0.14 A current through the load. That current will also have to go through the source impedance and cause a voltage drop and therefore also 1W of power dissipation there.

Requiring 2W of power to transmit 1W seems very inefficient so it seems very likely that there is something that I'm missing here.

Comment: Often it is simply done that way. At higher power levels, though, transformers are often used to transform source impedances and match the load to the actual power stage's output impedance.

Comment: Maybe. What kind of power amplifier you mean and is the output impedance resistive or not?

Answer (score 6):

If we consider a voltage source (such as your power amplifier) to consist of a zero-output impedance source \$V\$ in series with a non-zero impedance \$R_S\$, then your assumption is correct:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiKINU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since the same current is passing through both RS and RL, and RS and RL have the same value, then \$I^2R\$ power in each is the same.

Yes, it's inefficient, but if your goal is to eliminate reflections, which is really only of concern at radio frequencies, this is price you pay.

At low frequencies, we are usually not concerned with "transmission line" effects (unless the line is particularly long, or reactive), such as reflections, and we might be more concerned with power efficiency. To be efficient requires that the load impedance be significantly greater than the source impedance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foUBkh.png)</sup>

Again, current \$I\$ is the same in both RS and RL, but by making RS small compared to RL, we ensure that little power is lost in RS, and most is delivered to RL. Efficiency \$Q\$ will be the ratio of power arriving at the load, and power delivered by the source EMF (to *both* RS and RL):

$$ Q = \frac{I^2R_L}{I^2({R_S + R_L})} = \frac{R_L}{R_S+R_L} $$

Clearly, as \$R_S\$ decreases, or \$R_L\$ increases, so that \$R_L >> R_S\$, efficiency \$Q\$ approaches 100%.

All of this assumes that the impedances are all purely resistive. Any reactance present in the system will yield a different efficiency. An extreme example would be if the load were purely capacitive:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH62YL.png)</sup>

In this case, any energy delivered to ZL will eventually be returned to the source via RS. On average the capacitance dissipates no power at all, and any  current flowing will cause energy to be lost in RS. This system is 0% efficient.

---

Also, I should point out that it's perfectly possible to produce a near-zero output impedance power amplifier, using negative feedback, in a closed loop, but this does not mean that the elements responsible for sourcing/sinking load current are not dissipating power:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkC08k.png)</sup>

Everything inside the blue box can be considered to produce a signal at OUT with zero source impedance. All that means is that it doesn't matter what load you attach to OUT, no matter how much current you demand from that output, \$V_{OUT}\$ remains steady, equal to \$V_{IN}\$. OUT is as solid as a rock.

This does not mean that the blue box itself is 100% efficient. Don't forget that for Q1 and Q2 to provide some potential at OUT, they must necessarily have some voltage difference \$\pm 12V - V_{OUT} \$ across them, and they must also be passing current to supply the load. In other words, they are most definitely dissipating power as heat.

So, even though a voltage source may be considered to have negligible output impedance, this does not imply that its own internals aren't dissipating a lot of power to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: As an extra note to your first point: you can actually eliminate reflections without paying the price of the series source resistance by only terminating the cable on the far end, but you need to ensure it remains terminated--the series termination is intended to absorb reflections that make it back to the source, and if there are no such reflections it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily. The source impedance is a differential impedance. It is \$\frac{dV_{\rm out}}{dI_{\rm out}}\$ near the operating point. It isn't (usually) a series resistor  through which the signal must pass.

You'd want to consider a specific amplifier design and analyze it in particular to find out how its power dissipation relates to its output power. It might (for example) depend more on the output operating point voltage relative to the supply voltage, than on the signal power being delivered.

Answer (score 2):

You may have seen drawings where the amp has 50 ohm internal series resistor. One quite recent example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKINU.png Feeding a 50 ohm load resistor through it from a voltage source really dissipates as much in both resistors.

A power amp may have a factory spec: Load impedance should be 50 ohm. It tells nothing of the existence of the internal 50 ohm series resistance. It's well possible there's much less than 50 ohm (as already told by others) because very rare want to dissipate inside the amp as much as one gets to the load - not at least when he handles something more than few milliwatts. The spec =50 ohm load may be the allowed minimum and the load which takes the advertised maximum promised RMS output power (more commonly for audio amps there's said 2, 4 or 8 ohms instead of 50 ohms).

There can also be a LC filter which works properly only if there's a 50 ohm resistive load. The filter is the common case in radio transmitters.

In both cases the dissipation inside the amp can be much lower than what's taken into the load.